# First Dockerfile, I would appreciate critique

Tags: docker, dockerfile

As the title says, this is my first Dockerfile. It won't be published on any registry, just for my internal use at home. I'd appreciate any critique of what I could do better. I'm currently working on a way to not hard-code the password into the docker-compose file...

This image is to run Postfix on Alpine as a SMTP relay for my devices to alert me (e.g., NAS, security cameras, etc...).

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine:3.10

ARG BUILD_DATE

LABEL maintainer="MyNameGoesHere" \
      org.label-schema.schema-version="1.0" \
      org.label-schema.name="postfixrelay" \
      org.label-schema.build-date=$BUILD_DATE

RUN apk add --no-cache --update \
    bash ca-certificates cyrus-sasl-login postfix rsyslog tzdata && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

EXPOSE 25

VOLUME [ "/var/spool/postfix" ]

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /

RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh -e

#Set timezone
if [ ! -f /etc/timezone ] && [ ! -z "$TZ" ]; then
  cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime
  echo $TZ >/etc/timezone
fi

# Set Postfix options
postconf -e "inet_interfaces = all" && \
postconf -e "mynetworks = 0.0.0.0/0" && \
postconf -e "relayhost = [$RELAY_IP]:$RELAY_PORT" && \
postconf -e "smtp_use_tls = yes" && \
postconf -e "smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes" && \
postconf -e "smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous" && \
postconf -e "smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd"&& \
postconf -e "smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt" && \

# Create password file
echo "[$RELAY_IP]:$RELAY_PORT   $EMAIL:$PASS" > /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd && \
chown root:root /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd && \
chmod 600 /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd && \
postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd

# Start postfix
postfix start-fg
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  postfixrelay:
    container_name: postfixrelay
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - TZ=America/New_York
      - RELAY_IP=smtp.gmail.com
      - RELAY_PORT=587
      - EMAIL=my_email_address@gmail.com
      - PASS=password
    networks:
      - postfixrelay
    ports:
      - '25:25'
    volumes:
      - 'postfixrelay_data:/var/spool/postfix'
    image: postfixrelay

networks:
  postfixrelay:

volumes:
  postfixrelay_data:
    driver: local
```

Comment: shameless self-promotion   refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58393555/how-to-check-if-i-am-writing-the-right-dockerfile/58394030#58394030

Comment: You can split the `apk add ...` packages on multiple lines in your `Dockerfile`, makes it easier to see what's changed in i.e. a `git diff` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57747991/1423507). I'd move the `VOLUME` and `EXPOSE` to before the `RUN` as they'll probably never change. For the `networks` you can use the `default` setting the `name: postfixrelay` in your `docker-compose.yml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set the execute permissions on the `entrypoint.sh` before building the `docker` image - [RUN, COPY and ADD create layers](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#minimize-the-number-of-layers) - `COPY` preserves the file permissions so you can remove the `RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh` (a layer from your final image).

```
FROM alpine:3.10

ARG BUILD_DATE

LABEL maintainer="MyNameGoesHere" \
      org.label-schema.schema-version="1.0" \
      org.label-schema.name="postfixrelay" \
      org.label-schema.build-date=$BUILD_DATE

EXPOSE 25

VOLUME [ "/var/spool/postfix" ]

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /

RUN apk add --no-cache --update \
        bash \
        ca-certificates \
        cyrus-sasl-login \
        postfix \
        rsyslog \
        tzdata && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

... moved the `EXPOSE`, `VOLUME` and `COPY` instructions above the `RUN` - the `VOLUME` and `EXPOSE` are not likely to change and the build cache for the `COPY` will only be invalidated if the contents of the file changes as explained in the [`ADD` or `COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy) best practices. Finally, split the packages being added on multiple lines to make it clearer at a glance in i.e. a `git diff` when something changes.

Concerning the `entrypoint.sh` I'd suggest taking a look at the [Exec form `ENTRYPOINT` example](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example) to ensure that your process is receiving the Unix signals.

For the `docker-compose` I'd pass the `PASS` environment variable from the hosts environment and name the `default` network explicitly:

```
version: '3'
services:
  postfixrelay:
    container_name: postfixrelay
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      ...
      - PASS=${PASS}
...
networks:
  default:
    name: postfixrelay
...
```

If you want to `docker-compose up --scale postfixrelay=3` you'd need to stop using `container_name`, trying to start multiple containers with the same name will conflict. You'd also need to stop publishing the ports to the host, will have port conflicts - would need to set up a `tcp` load balancer (i.e. `nginx`, `traefik`, ...) and proxy the connections to your upstream services.

Then there is `docker swarm` and `kubernetes` (or other) as proper orchestration managers for your service(s).

Answer (score 0):

In `entrypoint.sh`, I prefer to have `set -eu` in line 2 instead of passing it in line 1. That way it is guaranteed to be set no matter how the program is run.

Because of this `set -e`, you can omit the `&& \`, since that code is neither in a subshell nor in a function. (The `set -e` mode is unreliable in either of them, I don't remember the exact rules though.)